# Find number of distinct pairs of numbers whose sum is equal to some 'K' - PHP

Tags: php, arrays

Given an array, I would like to display the count of distinct pairs of elements whose sum is equal to K -
I've written code as below, but I am unable to put array_diff to good use :\

```
<?PHP
function numberOfPairs($a, $k) {
    $cnt = 0;
    for($i=0; $i<count($a); $i++){
        for($j=$i; $j<count($a); $j++){
            if($a[$i]+$a[$j] == $k){
                $arrRes[$i][0] = $a[$i];
                $arrRes[$i][1] = $a[$j];
                $cnt++;
            }
        }
    }
    sort($arrRes);
    //print $cnt;
    $d = $cnt;
    for($i=0; $i<count($arrRes); $i++){
        for($j=0; $j<count($arrRes); $j++){
            $diff = array_diff($arrRes[$i], $arrRes[$j]);
            if($diff == null)
                $d += 1;
        }
    }
    print $d;
}

$a = [6,6,3,9,3,5,1];
$k = 12;
numberOfPairs($a, $k);
?>
```

Here, the output arrays with sum equal to 12 are, i.e, the result of $arrRes is -

```
[0] => Array ( [0] => 3 [1] => 9 ) 
[1] => Array ( [0] => 6 [1] => 6 ) 
[2] => Array ( [0] => 6 [1] => 6 ) 
[3] => Array ( [0] => 9 [1] => 3 )
```

The count is 4, but the count should be 2, as (6,6) and (3,9) are the only distinct pairs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a flat array with used numbers and check so that you don't use them again with in_array.

```
function numberOfPairs($a, $k) {
    $cnt = 0;
    $used=[];
    for($i=0; $i<count($a); $i++){
        for($j=$i; $j<count($a); $j++){
            if($a[$i]+$a[$j] == $k && !in_array($a[$i], $used) && !in_array($a[$i],$used)){
               $arrRes[$i][0] = $a[$i];
               $arrRes[$i][1] = $a[$j];
               $used[] = $a[$i];
               $used[] = $a[$j];
               $used = array_unique($used);
               $cnt++;
            }
        }
    }
    sort($arrRes);
    //print $cnt;
    // Not sure what the code below does, but I just left it the way it was.
    $d = $cnt;
    for($i=0; $i<count($arrRes); $i++){
        for($j=0; $j<count($arrRes); $j++){
            $diff = array_diff($arrRes[$i], $arrRes[$j]);
            if($diff == null)
                $d += 1;
        }
    }
    print $d;
}

$a = [6,6,3,9,3,5,1];
$k = 12;
numberOfPairs($a, $k);
```

Try it here https://3v4l.org/lDe5V

Answer (score 3):

You can simplify your solution, by using fact that arrays in php are hashmaps:

```
function numberOfPairs($a, $k) {
    $used=[];
    for ($i=0; $i<count($a); $i++)
        for ($j=$i+1; $j<count($a); $j++) {
            $v1 = min($a[$i], $a[$j]);
            $v2 = max($a[$i], $a[$j]);
            if ($k == $v1+$v2)
                $used[$v1.'_'.$v2] = true;
        }
    return count($used);
}

$a = [6,6,3,9,3,5,1];
$k = 12;
echo numberOfPairs($a, $k);
```

Answer (score 1):

Sort array and move indexes from both ends until they are not overlapped that gets O(n log n) instead of O(n^2) in accepted answer

```
function numberOfPairs($a, $k) {
  sort($a);
  $i = 0;
  $j = count($a)-1;
  // save last inseted array to avoid duplicates
  $last = [];
  while($i < $j) {
    $s = $a[$i] + $a[$j];
    if($s == $k) {
      $t = [$a[$i++], $a[$j--]];
      // Check for duplicate
      if ($t != $last) {
        $d[] = [$a[$i++], $a[$j--]];
        $last = $t;
      }
    }
    elseif($s > $k) $j--;
    else $i++;
  }
  return $d;
}
```

[**demo**](https://eval.in/928761)

Answer (score 1):

This is my method for finding distinct pairs of addends given an array and a target sum.

- `array_count_values()` will reduce the input array size by condensing duplicate addends and storing them as keys (and their number of occurrences as values).
- `ksort()` is called to ensure that the addends are processed in ascending order.  This is crucial to avoid processing addends that are beyond the midpoint of the number set.
- each iteration, store addends that are "less than or equal to" half of `k` AND have a matching addend.
- when the addend multiplied by 2 is "greater than or equal to" `k`, do not continue to iterate.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/LYhH6))

```
function numberOfPairs($a,$k){
    $a=array_count_values($a);  // enable use of the very fast isset() function and avoid iterating duplicates
    ksort($a);  // order so that only the lower values need to be iterated
    foreach($a as $num=>$occur){
        if(($double=$num*2)>=$k){ // we are at or past the middle
            if($double==$k && $occur>1) $result[]=[$num,$k-$num];  // addends are equal and 2 exist, store before break
            break;
        }elseif(isset($a[$k-$num])){  // matching addend found, store & continue
            $result[]=[$num,$k-$num];
        }
    }
    var_export($result);
}

$a = [6,6,3,9,3,5,1];
$k = 12;
numberOfPairs($a,$k);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    0 => 3,
    1 => 9,
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    0 => 6,
    1 => 6,
  ),
)
```

`array_count_values()` is probably the most expensive function call in the snippet, but it sets up all subsequent processes to be fast, concise, direct, and logical (and I think, readable).